# How to calculate fixed points and plot bifurcation diagram for non-linear ODE system

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, biology, bifurcation, nonlinear-dynamics

I am trying to understand how to analyse a system of coupled, non-linear ODEs taken from this  [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022519396902337?via%3Dihub). I want to perform a fixed point analysis and plot a bifurcation diagram to show how fixed points and their stability depend on the parameters.The setup is we have for example two cells, each characterized by its level of $n$ and $d$.

-$n_{i}$ represses the activity of its own $d_{i}$

-$d_{i}$ increases the activity of $d$ of its neighbour $d_{j}$

This is the non-dimensionalized form of the equations

$$\dot n_{i}=f(d_{j}) - n_{i}$$
$$\dot d_{i}=\nu (g(n_{i}) - d_{i})$$

where, $f=\frac{x^n}{a-x^n}$ and is monotonically increasing, $g=\frac{1}{1+bx^n}$ and is monotonically decreasing and $\nu$ represents a ratio of time constants $\frac{\gamma_d}{\gamma_{n}} $.

I honestly have no idea how to approach finding the fixed points, performing stability analysis and doing the bifurcation diagram, I care about dependence on $\nu,a,b$ and $n$.

If I take the case where $\nu >> 1$, I can simplify by assuming $d_{i}$ is in quasi steady state and hence $g(n_{i})=d_{i}$, therefore
$$\dot n_i = f(g(n_j)) - n_i$$
$$\dot n_j = f(g(n_i)) - n_j$$

which can be simplified further by substituting

$$\dot n_i = f(g(f(g(n_i))) - n_i$$
$$\dot n_j = f(g(f(g(n_j))) - n_j$$

and this is where i'm stuck. Usually in the 1d case you would solve for the fixed point and then check stability dependent on derivative and parameter values. I have no idea where to start from here.

Any pointers/help will be vastly appreciated. Also if this post is too long I will edit it down, I couldn't really decide what background is necessary so to understand things..

Comment: You can access the PhD Thesis on https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjwhoWF7LvuAhXGYcAKHfiNAhMQFjAGegQICxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdiposit.ub.edu%2Fdspace%2Fbitstream%2F2445%2F44311%2F11%2FPFJ_PhD_THESIS.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2N6_3TfH_E1rVUWbXwsuVX

Comment: thank you, I will look it over!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up brute-forcing it by simplifying fgfg using WolframAlpha, formulating the equation fgfg(x) - x = 0  and sovling it with a newton-rhapson root finder.

Producing the bifurcation diagram from there was easy.

I guess I was looking for a closed form way, where I get formulas for the fixed points dependent on parameters but I don't think that is possible or atleast I couldn't do it.